# Interface Builder background color => clear color?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, background-color

I've setup some background colors for my Labels in order to position them. Now that they are well in place, I would like to reset their background color to none, or clearColor.

But I don't find any way to achieve this in IB, I don't find any "no color" color...

Is there any way to do this without re-coding color at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give an alpha value? Try making it transparent :)

Comment: That's what I did for now, but I was thinking that revert it back to its default state was better.

Answer (score 4):

Set Opecity = 0 in Background option in IB

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in xcode 4

1. Select your label whose color you want to clear
2. In the Attributes Inspector in Inspector Window select the "clear color" option in the "Background" drop down menu. The same menu used to set the color of the labels.